# Kusto query for grouping AppInsights messages

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need the messages in Azure AppInsights grouped by the existence of particular substrings in the messages and the counts of these messages.

At the end, here is what the grouping would look like

```
messages                                  count
--------                                   -------
foomessages                               <say, 300>
barmessages                               <say, 450>
:
:
```

where

`foomessages = All messages containing the substring "foo" etc.`

How can I construct a query for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datatable(log: string) [
    "hello world",
    "this is a test",
    "this is a world test",
    "another test"
]
| summarize
    LogsWithWorld = countif(log has "world"),
    LogsWithTest = countif(log has "test")
| project Result = pack_all()
| mv-expand Result
| extend Message = tostring(bag_keys(Result)[0])
| extend Count = tolong(Result[Message])
| project Message, Count
```

The produced result is:

```
| Message       | Count |
|---------------|-------|
| LogsWithWorld | 2     |
| LogsWithTest  | 3     |
|---------------|-------|
```